# How can I refresh the Win10 login screen to show a newly created user without a reboot?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login-screen

I am using the Utilman.exe hack to create a new local Admin user at the Windows 10 login screen. However, it doesn't show up until I reboot the VM. How can I make it show up right away?

I tried `TaskKill /IM Explorer.exe /F` and `explorer.exe` via PowerShell, but that does not work. **What process/service/executable controls the display of the Windows 10 login screen?**

Comment: Log out of the current account and it will show up, log into the new account and windows will create the necessary folders and account settings.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot do that. I am simulating a hacking attempt for a Uni project, so I need to refresh the Win10 login screen.

Comment: I think only log out can accomplish this.

Comment: There has to be a service or executable that can be restarted...?

Comment: Im sure there may be but I don't know what it is.